# Azure Databricks parameter transfer between notebooks using Python

Tags: python, azure-databricks

The documentation by Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebook-workflows says that you can run another notebook and pass parameters by doing the following:

**notebook1:**

```
result = dbutils.notebook.run("notebook2", 60, {"argument": "data", "argument2": "data2"})
print(f"{result}")
```

But it doesnt say how I can fetch the paramters `argument` and `argument2` in my **notebook2**.

**notebook2:**

```
argument = ??
argument2 = ??
print(f"argument={argument} and argument2={argument2}")
dbutils.notebook.exit("Success")
```

How can I get get parameters in **notebook2**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document provided an answer for this. In order to get the parameters passed from `notebook1` you must create two text widgets using `dbuitls.widgets.text()` in `notebook2`. Now use the `dbuitls.widgets.get()` method to get the values of these parameters.

You can try using the following code:

- **Notebook1**

```
result = dbutils.notebook.run("nb2", 60, {"argument": "data", "argument2": "data2"}) 
print(f"{result}")
```

- **Notebook2**

```
dbutils.widgets.text("argument","argument_default") 
argument = dbutils.widgets.get("argument") 
  
dbutils.widgets.text("argument2","argument2_default") 
argument2 = dbutils.widgets.get("argument2") 
  
ans = argument+'    '+argument2 
  
#print(f"argument={argument} and argument2={argument2}") 
dbutils.notebook.exit(ans)
```

When you execute the notebook1 to run notebook2, the notebook2 runs successfully with the exit value as shown below:

```
data data2
```

Note: If pass only one value from, then the other argument in `notebook2` takes the default value mentioned in `dbutils.widgets.text()` (2nd parameter).

Comment: I tried the mentioned solution, but instead of data and data2, in my case 'argument' and 'argument2' itself are printed, ie, when i call get(), the variable name itself is returned instead of the value in the variable.